# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord: optimizing increment by one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an entry ID, which `popularity` has to be increased by one.

A simple solution looks like this:

```
Tag.find(id).increment!(:popularity)
```

However it doesn't seem to be very efficient, because I select the entire entry (*) from the database (even though I don't need it at all) and then do the second query to update it.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? I think, one update statement (without "select") should be enough, but how do I write this?

Comment: Well, you're going to run a query to find the right row to update no matter how you do this, so I don't think you can gain very much by replacing `Tag.find()` with some alternative update method. If you're using Rails 3, my understanding is AREL chains these things together to execute the minimum possible number of queries already.

Comment: But you should be able to do this with just one SQL query: "UPDATE `tags` SET `popularity` = `popularity` + 1 WHERE `id` = X" - am I missing something here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
Tag.increment_counter :popularity, id
```

Not only does this skip the select, but it increments atomically.

Comment: If you want to change by more than 1, see http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/update_counters

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like :

```
Tag.update_all("popularity = popularity + 1", {:id => id})
```

Or

```
Tag.where(:id => id).update_all("popularity = popularity + 1")
```

?